# Can I load an online javascript to current DOM and modify it a little before it is evaluated?

Tags: javascript

I could insert online javascript to the current DOM as below,

```
s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'http://url/script.js';
document.appendChild(s);
```

But Can I preload the script here and customize it a little before it is evaluatied? Is there any javascript could be used to do so?

EDIT: the last line in the above code shoudl be `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s)`

Comment: why wouldn't you just download it, change it, and host that? (I don't think it's possible btw)

Comment: which serverside script do u use btw, coz u would need a basic proxy that simply gets that script as text which you can later fetch from ajax, then manipulate it, and then load it inside a <script> tag or eval() everything.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @josh3736, I am trying to customize some server side javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use XHR to load it as text, modify it, then isert it as the content of a script element. It will not be executed until it is in the DOM.

Comment: ...not if it's hosted on a different domain, which appears to be the case.

Comment: but the problem will be on accessing a script from another website. For that you'd need jsonp, a callback function, and a proxy to do all that otherwise it will be a mess to load the whole javascript via callback.

Comment: @josh3736 - the XHR can request the resource from a same domain server, then the server gets the script and returns it to the client.

Answer (score 1):

You append script tags this way to the `head` object, not to the `document` object like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s).
```

And, when you load them this way, they will load asychronously and then execute as soon as they are loaded.  You will not be able to mess with them before they execute.  You can register to be notified when they are loaded and have successfully been executed, but can't control when they execute.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I lost the the element query part in my original code.